# 401 Unauthorized user not found node/mongo

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, passport.js

Hey I am trying to make a simple auth login system using mongodb and passport.js, the signup works, the problem is with the login. I have searched the world wide web for an answer but can't seem to find anything that fits my problem.

When trying to login with correct credentials I get this error message => [image]

**Login.jsx =>**

```
=> import { useState } from "react";

const Login = () => {
  const [error, setError] = useState("");
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    try {
      const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/auth/login", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          username: username,
          password: password,
        }),
      });

      console.log("Response from server:", response);

      if (response.ok) {
        const data = await response.json();
        console.log("Login successful");
      } else {
        const errorData = await response.json();
        console.log("Login failed:", error, errorData)
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Login error:", error);
      setError("An error occurred")
    }
  }

  return (
    <form method="post" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <div id="create-account" className="flex flex-col items-center pt-12">
        <div id="signup-text" className="pr-24">
        <div id="signup-text" className="flex items-center">
          <h1 className="font-semibold text-2xl">Login</h1>
          <span className="text-2xl ml-2"></span>
        </div>
          <h2 className="">Enter your details below to login</h2>
        </div>
        <div id="signup-container" className="pr-2">
        <div id="username" className="flex pt-2 space-y-3">
            <input
              type="username"
              onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}
              id="email-user"
              className="border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-80 p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500"
              placeholder="Email or Username"
              required
            />
          </div>
          <div id="password" className="flex items-center pt-2">
          <input
              type="password"
              id="pass"
              onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
              className="border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-80 p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500"
              placeholder="Password"
              required
            />
          </div>
            <button 
            type="submit" 
            className="mt-2 text-gray-900 bg-white border border-gray-300 focus:outline-none hover:bg-gray-100 focus:ring-4 focus:ring-gray-200 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-5 py-2.5 mr-2 mb-2 dark:bg-gray-800 dark:text-white dark:border-gray-600 dark:hover:bg-gray-700 dark:hover:border-gray-600 dark:focus:ring-gray-700">Login</button>
        </div>
        <div id="or" className="flex items-center pt-6">
          <hr className="flex-grow border-t border-gray-400" />
          <h2 className="px-4">Or</h2>
          <hr className="flex-grow border-t border-black-400" /> 
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  )
};

export default Login;
```

I also get this error from my server => [image]

**Server.js** =>

```
import express from "express";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import UserModel from "./database/models/user.js";
import mongoConnection from "./database/index.js";
import cors from "cors";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import session from "express-session";
import bcrypt from "bcrypt";
import passport from "passport";
import passportConfig from "./config/passport-config.js";
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken"; 
import { Strategy } from "passport-local";

const app = express();
const PORT = 3000;

// Middleware ----------------------
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// making sure requests from the client side work
app.use(cors({
  origin: "http://localhost:5173",
  credentials: true,
}));

// session cookies
app.use(
  session({
    secret: "secretcode",
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
  })
);

// ---- end of middleware

// signup
app.post("/user", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    // check if user or email already exists
    const existingUser = await UserModel.findOne({ username: req.body.username });
    const existingEmail = await UserModel.findOne({ email: req.body.email });

    if (existingUser) {
      return res.status(400).send("Username already exists");
    } if (existingEmail) {
      return res.status(400).send("Email already exists");
    }

    // hash password before save
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10);
    const user = new UserModel({
      username: req.body.username,
      email: req.body.email,
      password: hashedPassword,
    });

    // saving users to db/mongo
    await user.save();
    res.send(user);
    console.log("saved user: ", user)
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).send(error);
  }
});

passportConfig(passport);

// login
app.post("/auth/login", (req, res, next) => {
  console.log("Recieved login request:", req.body);
  
  passport.authenticate("login", (err, user) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("User found in the db:", user);

    if (!user) {
      res.status(401).json({ message: "No user exists" })
    }
    else {
      req.logIn(user, (err) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.send("Successfully Authenticated");
        console.log(req.user);
      });
    }
  })(req, res, next);
});
 
// starting server
app.listen(PORT, function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log("server could not start", err) 
  } else {
    console.log("Server listening on Port:", PORT)
  }
})
```

**User.js =>**

```
import { Schema, model } from "mongoose";
import bcrypt from "bcrypt";

// defining schema
const userSchema = new Schema({
  username: { type: String, required: true },
  email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  password: { type: String, required: true },
});


// comparing password, if true match
userSchema.methods.matchPassword = async function (password) {
  try {
    return await bcrypt.compare(password, this.password);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}

const UserModel = model("User", userSchema);

export default UserModel;
```

**Passport-config.js =>**

```
  import passport from "passport";
import UserModel from "../database/models/user.js";
import bcrypt from "bcrypt";
import { Strategy as LocalStrategy } from "passport-local";

export default (passport) => {
  // signup stratergy
  passport.use(
    "local-signup",
    new LocalStrategy(
      {
        usernameField: "email",
        passwordField: "password",
      },
      async (email, password, done) => {
        try {
          // Check if user already exists
          const userExists = await UserModel.findOne({ email: email });
          if (userExists) {
            return done(null, false);
          }

          // Create a new user with the provided data
          const user = await UserModel.create({ email, password });
          return done(null, user);
        } catch (error) {
          return done(error);
        }
      }
    )
  );

  // login stratergy
  passport.use(
    "login",
    new LocalStrategy(
      {
        usernameField: "username",
        passwordField: "password",
      },
      async (username, password, done) => {
        try {
          const user = await UserModel.findOne({ username: username });
          if (!user) {
            return done(null, false, { message: "User not found" });
          }
          
          const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
          if (!isMatch) {
            return done(null, false, { message: "Invalid password" });
          }

          // If passwords match, return the user
          return done(null, user);
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
          return done(error, false);
        }
      }
    )
  );
};

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user.id)
});

passport.deserializeUser(async (id, done) => {
  try {
    const user = await UserModel.findById(id);
    done(null, user);
  } catch (err) {
    done(err);
  }
});
```

Would greatly appreciate any help as I have been stuck on this for a while now!

Comment: I think I see the problem... _`usernameField: "user",`_. You're sending fields `username` and `password`

Comment: @Phil Good catch. What should I put there instead?

Comment: It doesn't matter, it just has to match what's actually in the request

Comment: @Phil, How do I now what's in the request?

Comment: Because you're making the request in Login.jsx

Comment: @Phil Thank you! I got it! Will update the q with the answer asap.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue was as phil described. My

```
usernameField: "username",
passwordField: "password"
```

Was not the same as the code being sent in the client.

Answer (score 0):

1. the Cors issue
   In relation to your cors issue, first open it up to all origins to test if that works for you. You can do that by

```js
// making sure requests from the client side work
app.use(cors());

or

// making sure requests from the client side work
app.use(cors({
  origin: "*"
}));
```

2. In relation to the user found in db:false. it could be one of many things
   To list a few:
3. Password hash comparison: Verify the password passed in the login route is being compared correctly
4. DB Query: Check what is return from the

   User.findOne({...})

Tip:
In the deserializeUser function, you have a typo. Replace await

```
user.findById(id); with await UserModel.findById(id);
```

to correctly retrieve the user by ID.

Comment: What _"cors issue"_?

Comment: Can you explain a little more what you mean by "cors issue"?

Comment: The first part of the question and the image you shared when you pass the correct credentials shows a 401 unauthorized error, indicating a cors issue as part of the response from the image as well. You can check the attached screenshot which has 'Response from server; ..... '. That is what i'm referring to as cors issue.

Comment: A 401 is not a CORS issue. If you're referring to the `type: 'cors'` in the screenshot, that is not an error. It's simply the [Response: type property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/type)